# How to reorder p:orderList controller buttons?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How can I reorder the controller buttons of a p:orderList? I am using PrimeFaces 5.0

Comment: Can you post the code you are trying and your problem is not clear. please describe

Comment: Why would you like to reorder them?  And jquery dom manipulation works allways

Comment: Krish - my question is very clear , simply i want to change order of  controll buttons of  p:orderList .

Comment: Ok, my question was not what you wanted to do but why... Might be that you think that something is wrong in the default order. Then I would have suggested to file an issue in the PF issue list. But since that is still not clear, my answer is below

Comment: And next time please share with us what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options you have are

- Using jquery dom manipulation
- Modifying the source of the PrimeFaces component and using that customized version
- Use css

The last one works, the first one works (I use jquery dom manipulation relatively often), the middle will work to, but might become a maintanance nightmare

CSS example:

```css
.ui-orderlist .ui-button.ui-orderlist-button-move-top {
    top: -30px !important;
}

.ui-orderlist .ui-button.ui-orderlist-button-move-up {
    top: 30px !important;
}
```

Remember that in the end, PrimeFaces is all just html, css and javascript (with jquery)

Comment: Client Requirement . Nothing more than that .

Comment: That's kind of the identical to answering 'because...'. But still... (since it is the first time I hear this request) what is the order they want them in (or in other words, what is wrong with the default order)

Comment: Took a look myself, and the current default order seems illogical. Filed an [issue 7917](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=7917)

Comment: Note that this CSS fix only works with older PrimeFaces versions! Newer versions use flex for positioning.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly neater CSS solution for modern browsers:

```
.ui-orderlist-button-move-up {
  order: 2;
}

.ui-orderlist-button-move-top {
  order: 1;
}

.ui-orderlist-button-move-down {
  order: 3;
}

.ui-orderlist-button-move-bottom {
  order: 4;
}
```

Comment: Note that this depends on your PrimeFaces version. You should have a CSS rule `body .ui-orderlist .ui-orderlist-controls { display: flex; ... }`. This will be the case with 13, but might not work with older versions (not sure when this was introduced.. wild guess: 10).